# Kill a process from lsof after ssh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, quoting

I know a process is running on a port 5000  on a remote server.
How can I call that in one-liner cmd ?

I can ssh to that server and do `kill $(lsof -i:5000 -t)`. It works.

From my local terminal if i do

```
ssh user@ip.ip.ip.ip "kill $(lsof -i:5000 -t)"
```

It gives error like

`kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]`

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused because your `$(lsof -i:5000 -t)` command is interpreted locally, and not remotely. Just use simple quotes to prevent local expansion. Alternatively, you can also escape the parts you do not want locally expanded.

```
ssh user@ip.ip.ip.ip 'kill $(lsof -i:5000 -t)'
# or
ssh user@ip.ip.ip.ip "kill \$(lsof -i:5000 -t)"
```

Basically, with `ssh` :

- Double quotes and regular variables (i.e : `$VAR`) : local expansion
- Single quotes and escaped variables (i.e : `\$VAR`) : remote expansion

Answer (score -1):

`ssh` to the system and do execute the command

```
 lsof -a +L1 | awk '$7 > 1073741824 && NR >1 {print $2}' | sort -nu | xargs kill
```

it will also cleared/released other blocked memory as well

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what that command is doing?  The `awk` bit is kind of obscure.